# Node.js how to reply with RegEx object, Hapijs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to write an endpoint to return a set of regular expressions we use in the web app, to standardize them from the server side.

```
  const myRegExp: RegExp = /^\d{10}$/;
  return reply(myRegExp);
```

The problem is this reply comes in as `{}` when called

If I reply with a string, a number, an object, anything in the world... it comes through the reply as expected. Replying with a param of type RegExp, returns an empty object `{}`

How can I send back a raw RegExp regular expression in my Node / Hapi endpoint?

Yes, I know I can reply with `myRegExp.source` and then re-create with `new RegExp(resp)`, but that seems silly unless I'm forced to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason hapi returns with an empty object is that the regexp object doesn't have any public properties. You can see that via your console.

```
> let x = new RegExp('/\d/')
> x
/\/d\//
> Object.keys(x)
[]
```

I think the right way to do it is that you can return **myRegExp.source** and then use it on your client-side code with `new RegExp(resp)` and it is not that silly.

Or you can just return your regexp definition as a string like

```
reply('/^\d{10}$/')
```

Then you can use it in your client code via `new RegExp(resp)`

I don't think it is possible directly returning evaluated regexp object from the server to the browser. Maybe you can do something like this;

```
reply(`const myRegExp = new RegExp(/^\d{10}$/);`).type("application/javascript");
```

Now you just loaded a javascript from the server, but I don't think it's useful.

Comment: Thanks @metoikos I ended up just doing it like that, `.source` and then `new RegEx`, frustrating it doesn't work the way it should but oh well